# Dynamically table columns and rows [Angular 6 + Bootstrap 3]

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6, bootstrap-grid

I need to create tables with dynamically columns and rows.
I have an array of objects, which I need to present in table.
But table need to be presented in 3 columns.
For example:

```
        var listItems = [
        { name: 'name1', code: 'code1'},
        { name: 'name2', code: 'code2' },
        { name: 'name3', code: 'code3' },
        { name: 'name4', code: 'code4' }
    ];
```

And table will look sth like:
**[name | code] [name | code] [name | code]** 
name1 code1 name3 code3 name4 code4 
name2 code2

What wil be the best solution?

Answer (score 4):

If items in the array are uniform then you can iterate over the keys.

```js
const list_items = [{name:'abc',code:'123'},{name:'def',code:'456'}];

let keys = Object.keys(list_items[0]); // Get the column names
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th *ngFor = 'let key of keys'>{{key}}</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor = 'let item of list_items'>
      <td *ngFor = 'let key of keys'>{{item[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is how to set this list into dynamic table in 3 columns?

Comment: @Wojciech what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: For example: when you'll have 2 items - you shows only two columns. When you'll have 8 items, you shows 3 columns (3 rows, 3 rows and 2 rows). For 9 items will be 3 columns (3 rows, 3 rows, 3 rows), and so on